# Nginx - Password Protect PHP Script

Tags: authentication, passwords, nginx

How can I password protect a single ph php script in Nginx. I'm using nginx as the webserver and proxying over to php-fastcgi. I can't get the location blocks to behave as expected.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying.

```
location /admin\.php$ {
    auth_basic "Valid User Required";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/http-auth;
}
location ~\.php$ {
    root /var/www/nginx/vhosts/site;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First issue:**

You are matching against a prefix string instead of a regular expression:

1. The prefix string is matched literally.
2. Even if a prefix string is matched, the search continues with the regular expression below (`~\.php$`). If that matches, the prefix string match is ignored.

**Solution to issue #1:**

Add a `~` to perform a regular expression match: `~/admin\.php$`.

**Second issue:**

Now that your block matches, you want to pass php scripts inside it to fastcgi, otherwise they'll be served as text files, without being parsed.

**Solution to issue #2:**

Nest a `~\.php$` location block inside the `~/admin\.php$` location block, for the final result shown below:

```
location ~/admin\.php$ {
    auth_basic "Valid User Required";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/http-auth;
    location ~\.php$ {
        root /var/www/nginx/vhosts/site;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
    }
}
location ~\.php$ {
    root /var/www/nginx/vhosts/site;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
}
```

---

**Reference:**

See this pertaining [post](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/password-protecting-directories-with-nginx/), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5238430/7659430) on location blocks precedence, and the Nginx [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
location /admin\.php$ {
    auth_basic "Valid User Required";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/http-auth;
+    root /var/www/nginx/vhosts/site;
+    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
+    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
+    fastcgi_pass phpfcgi;
}
```

May be this helps to you.