# LiipImagineBundle not working on production environment

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle, vichuploaderbundle

I use `LiipImagineBundle 1.6.0` on `Symfony 3.1.3` combined with `VichUploaderBundle 1.2.0` and everything goes fine on `dev` but on `prod` he doesn't save cached files. Images are saving correctly so there is rather not a problem of `VichUploaderBundle`.

config.yml:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm # or mongodb or propel or phpcr
    mappings:
            pop_image:
                uri_prefix:         /images/pops
                upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/pops
            ad_image:
                uri_prefix:         /images/ads
                upload_destination: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/ads
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       default:
          web_path: ~

    filter_sets:
        cache: ~
        square:
            quality: 75
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [400, 400], mode: outbound }
```

routing.yml:

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

twig:

```
...
<div class="image">
   <img src="{{ vich_uploader_asset(pop,'imageFile')|imagine_filter('square') }}" alt="{{ pop.question }}" width="100%" class="grayscale" />
   <span class="image-question">{{ pop.question }}</span>
</div>
...
```

Comment: So the problem is that the cached files are not created or the url is not generated ?

Comment: @Florent The cache files are not generated.

Comment: And you cleared your cache ? Problems between dev and prod environment come from not clearing cache 90% of the time ! :)

Comment: @Florent Yes, of course. I start think that this is nginx configuration problem. I read somewhere that nginx does some redirections before LiipImagineBundle create cache files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm faced with a similar problem but with `LiipImagineBundle 2.1` on `Symfony 4.2`.
In my case, Nginx rule that I used for caching images overrides the route of `LiipImagineBundle`.

```
    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # Cache images.
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
        access_log off;
    }
```

So, I've added a separate location for `/media/cache/resolve/`:

```
    location ^~ /media/cache/resolve/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

The `^~` prefix tells Nginx to stop looking for other locations (more about [Nginx location priority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5238430/10518871)).

Comment: I've added the new rule at the beginning then at the end of the config : the problem remains ! I'm using Liip2.3/Sym4.4
Here is the entire nginx config file : https://www.writeurl.com/text/uquirzbmy51zsfyu4zi9/bknz0bvihor2l3pffznt

Comment: @Sami, I think that `if` inside your `location /` is blocking rule for `/media/cache/resolve/`.