# nginx location 404 not found

Tags: nginx, location, http-status-code-404, nginx-location, nginx-config

Here are my nginx configure files.

On the default.conf, the first location is used to access /usr/share/nginx/html directory, it is ok while I access http://47.91.152.99. 
But when I add up a new location for directory /usr/share/nginx/public directory, nginx return me a 404 page while I access http://47.91.152.99/test.

So, what is the matter? Am I misuse the directive of nginx?

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}


/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ^~ /test/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/public;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `http://47.91.152.99/test/` (with a trailing `/`)? Is the file located at `/usr/share/nginx/public/test/index.html`?

Comment: Yes, with a trailing /. And index.html is in the directotry.

Comment: `index.html` is in which directory? Your question implies `/usr/share/nginx/public`, but your configuration file uses `/usr/share/nginx/public/test`

Comment: The reason is you set your Debug to False, so you won't see the response from http://47.91.152.99. If you would like to see the response from http://47.91.152.99 set your Debug to True

Answer (score 41):

You seem to be misusing the [**root**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive in the following block;

```
 location ^~ /test/ {
     root /usr/share/nginx/public;
     index index.html index.htm;
 }
```

The previous block, as you use it, is telling nginx to look for directory `test` into the folder `/usr/share/nginx/public`. If there's no accessible `test` folder at that location, nginx will return a 404. To solve this problem, i suggest using [**alias**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) instead of [**root**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive, like so;

```
 location ^~ /test/ {
     alias /usr/share/nginx/public;
     index index.html index.htm;
 }
```

In this block, which uses [**alias**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) instead of [**root**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive, a request for `domain.com/test/somefile.jpg` would look for file `somefile.jpg` into `/usr/share/nginx/public`.

Look for more information on [**alias** directive on nginx.org](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Also, just for kicks, [**index**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) directive can be set generally so you don't have to re-write it all the time, like so;

```
 server {
     listen       80;
     server_name  localhost;

     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     index  index.html index.htm;

     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

     location / { }

     location ~^/test/ {
         alias /usr/share/nginx/public;
     }

     location = /50x.html {
         root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }
 }
```

One thing you should also consider... the more 'precise' the location block, the higher in your config it should reside. Like that `location = /50x.html`. In a perfect world, that would be set up top, right after the general server block settings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. I still get the 404 not found response.

Comment: When access the url http://47.91.152.99/test, I want nginx server access the root directory /usr/share/nginx/public.

Comment: It will be a match for requests starting with /images/ (location / also matches such requests, but has shorter prefix).

The resulting configuration of the server block should look like this:

server {
    location / {
        root /data/www;
    }

    location /images/ {
        root /data;
    }
}

Comment: After I create test directory under /usr/share/nginx/public, then the response is okay. Thank you for you reply.

Answer (score 15):

## Error caused by root directive

```
location ^~ /test/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/public;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

## Fix with alias directive

```
 location ^~ /test/ {
     alias /usr/share/nginx/public;
     index index.html index.htm;
 }
```

## Other Improvements

Extra tip: the index directive can be set so that you don't have to re-write it.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location / { }

    location ~^/test/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/public;
    }

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

nginx matches Location blocks partly based on position in the config. Ideally, you would invert what you have now. The location block would be higher in nginx config. To that end, the  location = /50x.html would also move up. Order is

1. Exact match =
2. Forward match ^~ /
3. Case sensitive regex ~ /
4. Case insensitive regex ~*
5. Path match /

More about [nginx location priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority). Also, you can always review the official documentation. The nginx documentation for location block http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Moderator comment: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."  Comment wasn't long enough. What would you have preferred?

Answer (score 1):

when your app is vuejs，you need write like this,can prevent 404,pay attention to double /test/

```
   location ^~/test/ {
       alias /usr/local/soft/vuejs/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;
    }
```

Comment: there is not alot of value added here. Specially with using such a bloating try_files directive. $uri and $uri/ are already beeing seen and dealt with by nginx nature so nothing useful in using this. In the same respect, having index.html with the same path as the location block makes no sens and again, is something that the 'index' directive takes care of without the need to explicitly repeat it. There is no harm in doing it, per say, but certainly doesnt help anyone understand the concepts as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this (index.html not found) issue. 
For me, I misstyped my project name to match your ec2 project name with the nginx path.

Move to nginx/sites-enabled to check nginx path

1. cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
2. `cat` your_project_name
3. Check your nginx path
   (for me : root/home/ubuntu/**practice**/current/public;)

Move to home directory to check your project name
4. cd
5. ls
6. If your ec2 project name(for me: practice) is not match with your nginx path name(for me: practice) then you might got "index.html not found error"

Comment: I must stress that the 'site-enabled' and disabled directory format comes from Apache httpd and is usually found on Debian and similar distrubutions. A native nginx distributed package does NOT include such directories. Also, it is of note that wherever you put your configuration files, nginx.conf must have the needed 'include' directive in order to process it.

Comment: This looks more like a general, very basic tutorial in using a keyboard, legacy tools and proper 'grammar' related to the environment

Answer (score 0):

and my server-blocks.conf

```
server {

        listen 80;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 13.xxx.xxx.xx;

        location / {
        root /var/www/portaladmin/;


                proxy_pass http://13.xxx.xxx.xx:80/;

        }
         error_log /var/log/nginx/portaladmin-erorr.log;

}
```

and my load-balancer.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xx
  access_log /home/ec2-user/logs/lb-access.log;
  error_log /home/ec2-user/logs/lb-error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://13.xxx.xxx.xx:80;
           }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Creating **nginx** & **sftp** pods using Kubernetes.. I've found that the **mountPath** in my **sftp-deployment.yaml** file is related to the username in my **sftp-server**.

And the error has happened when I have changed the **username** without changing **mountPath** value to match my username. So, the files were uploading to ***'/home/old-username'*** instead of ***'/home/new-username'***.

Answer (score 0):

cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/
sudo nano default

in this config file in https or server

$url /$url /index.html