# Nginx - how to add header for index.html when using try_files

Tags: nginx, http-headers, cache-control

I have the following config (for an Angular app):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    add_header "Cache-Control" "no-cache" ;
}
```

Now I would like to add that header only for `index.html`, but not for any other files. How to do that?

Comment: try to  add  location= /index.html { //here you add the directive }

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: Directives with the "=" prefix that match the query exactly. If found, searching stops.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5238430/6229548

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI
>   and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates.

so   you can use this configure :

```
location =/index.html {
      add_header "Cache-Control" "no-cache" ;
}
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)  /index.html  break;

}
```

---

you can find more information in

[different in break and last](https://serverfault.com/questions/131474/nginx-url-rewriting-difference-between-break-and-last)

[Directives with the "=" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5238430/6229548)