# Why may nginx ignore proxy_read_timeout inside location context?

Tags: nginx, http-proxy, nginx-location

Config looks like:

```
server {
    ...
    proxy_read_timeout 45s;
    ...

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://ADMIN_APP_IP:8000;
    }

    location /admin/analytics {
        proxy_read_timeout 900s;
    }
}
```

For some reason, when I send a request to https://mystageaddr.com/admin/analytics/ `proxy_read_timeout` inside `location /admin/analytics` seems to be ignored, because after `45s` nginx returns 504 error. If I change `proxy_read_timeout` value inside server context everything works fine.

The documentation says that it should be ok to use `proxy_read_timeout` inside `location` http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout, maybe I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

It was my fault, I forgot about nginx location priorities ([Nginx location priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority)), I had a regular expression in my config that had a bigger priority.