# Nginx Fast CGI cache ON error_page 404

Tags: php, nginx, caching, http-status-code-404

I would like to cache (fast_cgi) 404 response.

```
error_page 404 = /url_rewriting.php;
```

In my url_rewriting.php I generate image with php:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'render/framed/file') !== FALSE) {
    $urlBlocks = ['VR', 'sizePixels', 'image', 'ver', 'frame', 'borderSize', 'mat', 'matSize', 'maxSize', 'frameGlass', 'minSize'];
    foreach($urlBlocks as $oneBlock) {
        if($pos = array_search($oneBlock, $urlParts)) {
            if(isset($urlParts[($pos+1)]) && $urlParts[($pos+1)] != '') {
                $_GET[$oneBlock] = urldecode($urlParts[($pos+1)]);
            }
        }    
    }

    chdir('include/php/render/framed');
    header('Status: 200 OK', false, 200);
    require ('include/php/render/framed/render_img.php');
}
```

By this way, I can have image src URL in the HTML like this :

`https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/file/VR/1/size/300/image/U3dpwK/the-cat.jpg`

which jpg file does not exist but is generated by PHP.

But I didn't find any way with Nginx to cache theses php generated images.

I tried this:

```
set $no_cache 0;

location ~ /render/ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
        fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
        fastcgi_cache PROD;
        fastcgi_cache_valid any 20d;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 404 20d;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
        expires 10M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

It's working for image URL

```
https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/img.php?VR=1&size=300&image=U3pmwKi
```

but not for image URL

```
https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/file/VR/1/size/300/image/U3dpwK/the-cat.jpg
```

Yet I have put `fastcgi_cache_valid 404 20d;`

So, how to cache scripts going on `error_page 404 = /url_rewriting.php;`?

***EDIT***

Here are 2 `curl -I` output:

Non working URL (For cache)

```
curl -I "https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/file/VR/1/sizePixels/300/image/SzDuehqyda%3D/ver//frame/black-e91-2/borderSize/1.70/mat/zkadhtcoz/matSize/10/maxSize/800/minSize/600/freedom.jpg"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 14:59:24 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: Mywebsite=vmegg0qk7udtmkmcathd329kkp; expires=Sun, 03-Jun-2018 14:59:24 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/
Cache-Control: private, max-age=31536000, pre-check=31536000
Pragma: private
Last-Modified: Sat, 01 Apr 2000 13:13:45 GMT
Content-transfer-encoding: binary
Expires: Sat, 08 Jun 19 15:59:24 +0100
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

Working URL (For cache)

```
curl -I "https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/render_img.php?VR=1&sizePixels=360&image=SzDuehqyda%3D&ver=&frame=black-e91-2&borderSize=1.70&mat=zkadhtcoz&matSize=10&maxSize=800&minSize=600"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 14:59:59 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=25920000
Pragma: private
Last-Modified: Sat, 01 Apr 2000 13:13:45 GMT
Content-transfer-encoding: binary
Expires: Thu, 28 Feb 2019 14:59:59 GMT
Cache-Control: public
X-Cache-Status: HIT
```

***EDIT2***

Output of `nginx -t`

```
root@mywebsite-london-01:/var/www/mywebsite.com/prod# nginx -T
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        #  Adding GeoIP for Matomo
        ##
        geoip_country  /var/www/geoip/GeoIP.dat;
        geoip_city     /var/www/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat;

        # Max File upload
        client_max_body_size 100m;

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
        log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                               '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
                               '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        #       gzip on;
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# CACHE (Images rendering)
fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/cache/l7 levels=1:2 keys_zone=L7:1m max_size=100m inactive=20d;
fastcgi_cache_path /var/www/cache/prod levels=1:2 keys_zone=PROD:100m max_size=10000m inactive=30d; # For PROD

add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status; #To check what is that for

# SSL

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
ssl_session_timeout 180m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DHE+AES128:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/cert/dhparam.pem;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com l7.mywebsite.com cdn.mywebsite.com dev.mywebsite.com;

        set $rootfolder "prod";
        set $ask_auth "Restricted Area";
        if ($host ~ "l7.mywebsite.com") {
                set $rootfolder "l7";
                set $ask_auth off;
        }

        root /var/www/mywebsite.com/$rootfolder;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com-access.log compression buffer=32k;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite.com-error.log;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        error_page 404 = /url_rewriting.php;

        set $no_cache 1;
        if ($request_uri ~* "render_img.php") {
            set $no_cache 0;
        }

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                #auth_basic            $ask_auth;
                #auth_basic_user_file  .htpasswd;
        }

        set $no_cache 0;
        #location ~ render_img.php  {
        location ~ /render\/framed/ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

                fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
                fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
                fastcgi_cache PROD;
                fastcgi_cache_valid any 20d;
                fastcgi_cache_valid 404      1d;
                #fastcgi_cache_valid any 20d;
                #fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503 http_404;
                fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503;
                fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
                fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
                fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
                fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
                expires 10M;
                access_log off;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

                fastcgi_buffers 8 16k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k; # increase the buffer size for PHP-FTP

                fastcgi_param GEOIP_ADDR $remote_addr;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_REGION $geoip_region;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_REGION_NAME $geoip_region_name;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_CITY $geoip_city;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_AREA_CODE $geoip_area_code;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_LATITUDE $geoip_latitude;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_LONGITUDE $geoip_longitude;
                fastcgi_param GEOIP_POSTAL_CODE $geoip_postal_code;

                if ($rootfolder = "l7") {
                        access_log /var/log/nginx/mywebsite_l7.com-access.log;
                }


        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}


server {
    if ($host = dev.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = cdn.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = l7.mywebsite.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com l7.mywebsite.com cdn.mywebsite.com dev.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

**SOLUTION**

As said by Tarun Lalwani, the block priority and order matters. But also, when you want to cache 404 response, you have to check it on the filename of error_page:

```
location ~ (render_img.php|^/url_rewriting.php$) {
    fastcgi_cache...stuffs to cache...
}
```

We cannot check `location ^~ /render/framed/ {` as it's a 404 response which corresponds to `/url_rewriting.php`.

Comment: What is the output of `curl -I "https://mywebsite.com/include/php/render/framed/file/VR/1/size/300/image/U3dpwK/the-cat.jpg"`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have edited my message to add 2 output of `curl -I` Thank you for your help.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, sorry. corrected and I updated my EDIT.

Comment: I think you have some other block handling this, that is why. Run `nginx -T` to dump complete config. You have another block which is why it not hitting the cache. If it was hitting and missing the cache the Header would have been returned with a `MISS` value

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have added the output of `nginx -T`. It's quite a lot and I didn't notice what would prevent to cache a 404 response. The server l7 server is a dev server on which I make tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170397/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-london-smith).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to give priority to your block of `.php` and not `/render/framed/` when a `.php` is called in that location. It is still caught by the `.php` block

So you need to use below for your location block. You need to use

```
location ^~ /render/framed/ {
  ...
}
```

For understanding the same in details refer to

[Nginx location priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority)

Comment: Personally I'd handle the caching headers from php not in the webserver config.

Comment: @symcbean, that again may be a personal opinion. For me a app should be concerned about functionality and not caching. Caching should be handled at the web server level. This gives better control on how you setup the app in a different environments. But as I said these are all personal opinions or preferences. There is no wrong or right here