# root context with preference over a regular expression

Tags: nginx

I have read the documentation and seems it is the same as explained here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority), but during my tests the root context is having precedence over the regular expression one.

Does anyone know the reason?

See my nginx.conf file and a test curl I did to validate the configuration:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                                      
        location ~ /ui(/.*) {
            try_files $1 $1/ @htmlext;
        }                             
         
        location @htmlext {
            rewrite ^/ui(/\w*)(/.*)*$ $1.html last;
        }                                          
         
        location / {
            return 301 /ui$request_uri;
        }
    }
}

/ # curl -v http://localhost/ui/message?msg=error.forbidden
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /ui/message?msg=error.forbidden HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.67.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.19.0
< Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2020 22:34:49 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Location: http://localhost/ui/ui/message?msg=error.forbidden
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

As you can see in the curl it is redirecting my /ui/message page instead of rendering it. If I remove the **location /** from the configuration it seems working, if I remove the @htmlext location and add that logic in the **location ~ /ui(/.*)** it seems working too. Then I think the reason of my error is the @htmlext redirect.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Your `location /` block matches **any** URI that does not begin with `/ui`. So as soon as the URI is rewritten to `/message.html` it generates the return 301.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. By the way, that does not happen when I remove the `location @htmlext` and change the first one to `location ~ /videocon(/\w*)(/.*)*$ { try_files $1 $1/ $1.html last; }`. Do you know why?

Comment: Yes. The *file* terms of the `try_files` statement are evaluated within the same `location` context. The `rewrite...last` restarts the search for a `location` block and finds the one containing the `return 301`.