# Kubernetes Ingress with mixed locations

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a kubernetes ingress that has a service taking advantage of `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`. I have another path, `service1/query` that needs to redirect somewhere other than what the `rewrite-target` is pointing to. Let's say it should act as a proxy and forward the request to google.com and return the result. Because the `rewrite-target` is for *all* paths defined, I'm not sure how I should proceed to differentiate the path for `service1/query`.

Any ideas?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myApp
  namespace: myApp
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: '$http_origin'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - myhost.org
    secretName: ingress-nginx-tls-cert
  rules:
  - host: myhost.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: service1
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /service1/query
        pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: Have you already tried any solutions? What version of Ingress-NGINX are you using?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what solutions are out there for this, given that `rewrite-target` is for *all* paths defined. NGINX 1.19

Comment: You can update the path for your second service as `path: /service1/query(/|$)(.*)` Does this solve your problem?

Comment: You can create another ingress resource almost identical, but excluding `rewrite-target` and `path: /service1(/|$)(.*)`. The location matching priority of Nginx should automatically route only requests for `/service1/query` to your new Ingress and everything else to the one above.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238377/nginx-location-priority

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to change the paths' order. [Ingress Path Matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)

```
paths:
  - path: /service1/query
    pathType: Prefix
  - path: /service1(/|$)(.*)
    pathType: Prefix
    backend:
      service:
        name: service1
        port:
          number: 80
```

When you add `/service1(/|$)(.*)` to the first line, the `/service1/query` is a dead code; because it enters the first line.

However, if you put `/service1/query` to the first; nginx will look at it first.